# Match Nothing or pattern in regular expressions

Tags: ios, regex, xcode, nsregularexpression

I am trying to validate fields in my iOS program:
I need to match a phone number, but the field is optional.
I thought using the regex to match the number to also validate if there is no phone number:

```
[0-9\-\+\*]{4,14}
```

Then I thought how to also match where there is either a valid number or no number at all?

```
(:?[0-9\-\+\*]{4,14})?
```

Meaning, either match between 4 to 14 chars within the range 0-9,+,-,* or nothing.
[This website](http://www.regexpal.com) is showing infinte matches for that pattern.

ideas?

Comment: Just use anchors and an optional group: [`^(?:[0-9+*-]{4,14})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/oT5qY0/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^$|^[0-9\-\+\*]{4,14}$
```

As to the questions this has brought here:
Regex is a great validation method. and it is cross platform.
no need for another layer of code to implement. Simple and clean.

Answer (score -1):

You should just code it. I don't know your language but basicaly :

```
If(field.isEmpty)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Regex patterns can match an empty string with `^$` or `\A\z`.

Comment: They can but what's the purpose ? Isn't it faster to code it natively ?

Comment: That is a different question. I just say it is possible. What is better depends on what OP wants or already has, or his boss it telling him to do.